# Cypher query in Scala using Scala-Neo4j wrapper

Tags: scala, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I tried a simple Cypher query in Scala using Scala-Neo4j wrapper like below

```
val article_index = getNodeIndex("article").get
val query = "start n=node:article_index('article_id:*') return n"
val t = query.execute.asCC[article]("n")
println(t.next())
```

The code is compiling with out any errors. But, when I run it I get the following errors

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.<init>(Lorg/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService;)V
    at org.neo4j.scala.Cypher$class.engine(Cypher.scala:71)
    at dum.User_node$.engine(User_node.scala:38)
    at org.neo4j.scala.Cypher$$anon$1.execute(Cypher.scala:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Please inclue a self-contained example, it will be easier for people to help you. You might have a classpath problem, a mismatch between the jars used to compile vs run your code. How do you run your code?

Comment: There is no problem with classpath and jars. All the other functions are working perfectly. Syntax is incorrect I guess!

Comment: Your example *runs*, meaning it passed compiler checks. It's not a syntax error. `NoSuchMethodError` is a sign that the compiler *thinks* a certain method exists (at compile-time), but at runtime it doesn't find it. That's a sign the jar used to *run* the program is different than the one used to compile it.